# cant display the data from controller

Tags: php, frameworks, codeigniter-2

My problem is that I can't get data in database but if I use `var_dump()` I have data. This is the error:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined index: projectid Filename: views/accounting_status.php Line Number: 46

This is my View

This page was accesed incorrectly.

```
<div class="well">
<p><h1><?=$p['projectid']?></h1></p>
<p><?=$p['code']?></p></div>
```

This is my Controller

```
function id($projectid){
    $data['p'] = $this->Accounting_Model->get_awardedid($projectid);
    //echo "<pre>".print_r($data)."</pre>";
    $this->load->view('tmp_header');
    $this->load->view('accounting_status',$data);
}
```

This is my Model

```
function get_awardedid($projectid){
    $this->db->select('*')->from('projects')
                          ->join('customer', 'projects.customerid = customer.customerid')
                          ->join('employees', 'projects.endorse_by = employees.employeeid')
                          ->where(array('acctg'=>1,'projectid'=>$projectid))
                          ->order_by('datecreated', 'desc');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: first check using vardumps and print_r is there any index named *projectid*.I think there is no index in the returned array named projectid

Comment: Print out `$p` in your view.  Are you sure a row exists?  You aren't doing any checks to make sure.

Comment: put your result of `echo "<pre>".print_r($data)."</pre>";` in question.

Comment: i use vardump and i have a record select but when i display the record it says the above error

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> array(51) { ["projectid"]=> string(4) "1696"

Comment: try `<?=$p['0']['projectid']?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the result will be a single row then change on model as follows:

```
function get_awardedid($projectid){
    $this->db->select('*')->from('projects')
                          ->join('customer', 'projects.customerid = customer.customerid')
                          ->join('employees', 'projects.endorse_by = employees.employeeid')
                          ->where(array('acctg'=>1,'projectid'=>$projectid))
                          ->order_by('datecreated', 'desc');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If result is multiple records, then use for loop to print the values in view.

```
<div class="well">foreach($p as $value){<p><h1><?=$value['projectid']?></h1></p><p><?=$value['code']?></p>}</div>
```